# Want Different value from @Html.HiddenFor from a for loop

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How Can I get the value for the exact "PostId" in my javascript each time user click on the image

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{

<img src="/images/icon_edit.gif" width="22" height="19" class="Edit" itemid="post" />
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].PostId, new { @class = "postnew" })    
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.Edit').click(function () {
      alert($("#post").val());

      var params = { uname: $(this).val() };

      $.ajax({
          url: "/Profile/Post",
          type: "Get",
          data: { id: $("#post").val() }     
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can render the post id as a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) and access that using jQuery.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{    
  <img src="/images/icon_edit.gif" width="22" height="19" class="Edit" data-post-id="@x[i].PostId" />   
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.Edit').click(function () {
      var $this = $(this), id = $this.data('postId');

      $.ajax({
          url: "/Profile/Post",
          type: "Get",
          data: { id: id }     
      });
  });
});
```

The resulting `img` markup will look something like:

```
 <img src... data-post-id="1" ... />
```

With jQuery, you can read attributes using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/). Names separated by hyphens will be camelCased, hence `postId`.

## However, we can do better...

1. Consider using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to handle all current and future click events to elements decorated with `.Edit`. This is useful if it is possible that new elements with `.Edit` will be added to the DOM later, as they will automatically be included.

   ```
    $(document).on('click', '.Edit', function() { /* ... */ });
   ```
2. Consider using semantically meaningful markup, and wrap the image in an anchor, rather than make an img clickable. Then, simply add an `href` to the anchor to the URL for the post. You can then do away with the data attribute and simply your AJAX call.

   ```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
   {    
      <a href="@Url.Action("Post", "Profile", new{id = x[i].PostId})" class="Edit"><img src="/images/icon_edit.gif" width="22" height="19" /></a>
   }

   $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '.Edit', function () {
         var url = $(this).attr('href');

         $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: "Get"  
         });
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: As a side note if you are creating data attributes using HTML helpers then you have to underscore your attribute e.g. new { data_attribute_id = 1 }. Mvc then renders this as data-attribute-id="1". Unrelated but maybe useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with data attribute is good but if you want to use the hidden field you can use jQuery **next()** selector.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.Edit').click(function () {

      // the 'next' hidden field for the img
      var id = $(this).next().val(); 

      $.ajax({
          url: "/Profile/Post",
          type: "GET",
          data: { id: id }     
      });
  });
});
```